# Custom Spring properties files with profile-dependent loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

We are currently having one `application.properties` and one `application-staging.properties`, which is loaded based on the **active Spring profile**.

However, it's very **bloated** and we like to **split** it into **multiple properties files** based on the context.

For example:

`teams.properties` and
`teams-staging.properties`

We load it using the class below

```
@Getter
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:teams.properties")
public class TeamsProperties {

    @Value("${teams.some-team-a}")
    private String someTeamA;

    @Value("${teams.some-team-b}")
    private String someTeamB;

}
```

But it **won't respect the profile** and the `teams-staging.properties` is ignored.

**What would be needed to "clone" the default application.properties behaviour for custom properties files?**

Comment: Intuitive approach: you'd "multiply" (extend!;) your `TeamsProperties` with (each) different `@Profile` and `@PropertySource` combination(!)

Comment: @xerx593 this would be an insane overhead if I do that across all property groups

Comment: True! ..tricky solution/workaround/plugging: you write in your `application[-profile].properties` : `spring.config.import=teams[-profile].properties` (omitting the need for `@PropertySource`;)

Comment: Interesting, thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: something like this would also be amazing ```@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:teams.properties"),
        @PropertySource(profile = "staging", value = "classpath:teams-staging.properties")
})``` to specify an optional profile within the PropertySource

Answer (score 2):

@PropertySource accept an array as value. You can do this :

```
@Getter
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:teams.properties", "classpath:teams-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"})
public class TeamsProperties {
    
    @Value("${teams.some-team-a}")
    private String someTeamA;
    
    @Value("${teams.some-team-b}")
    private String someTeamB;
    
}
```

Then run the application with the active profile :

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=staging
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that you always have to pass only one active profile. It will not work for multiple profiles : `-Dspring.profiles.active=foo,bar`

**Edit:**

@MarianKlühspies Following your answer, you can have more flexibily using YAML instead of properties file to achieve this behavior.

```
spring:
    config:
        activate:
            on-profile: staging
name: staging-profile
environment: staging
enabled: false
...

---
spring:
config:
    activate:
        on-profile: prod
name: production-profile
environment: production
enabled: true 
...
```

Comment: Thank you. It will also not work exactly as the way it does with application.properties, as it's required to have one teams-production.properties instead, and without it the application won't start. And it would also be required to have another file for testing. Sadly all provided sources have to be available in the classpath

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to do it via inheritance as **@xerx593** recommended in the comment.

```
@Getter
public abstract class TeamsProperties {

    @Value("${teams.some-team-a}")
    private String someTeamA;

    @Value("${teams.some-team-b}")
    private String someTeamB;


    @Configuration
    @Profile({"!staging"})
    @PropertySource({"classpath:teams.properties"})
    public static class TeamsPropertiesDefault extends TeamsProperties {

    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile({"staging"})
    @PropertySource({"classpath:teams-staging.properties"})
    public static class TeamsPropertiesStaging extends TeamsProperties {

    }

}
```

The reason is, I'd like to keep **teams.properties** as the **default** properties file and only then switch to staging if the profile is staging. I also don't want to have to create one additional .properties file for each profile, like "testing".

So with that way, each profile that is not covered with a specific properties file **will always fall back** to **teams.properties** ( but the **@Profile** annotation of the default must be enhanced of course)

Putting it all together with inner classes keeps it relatively **clean** and I can live with it.

Comment: I see clearly now what you want to achieve. You can have more flexibily using YAML instead of properties file by using `spring.config.activate.on-profile:stagin`